# Trapping error in R

Tags: r, try-catch

A very basic quesiton. But i am not able to apply this to my code. Hence seeking help here

I am getting an error mentioned below while running this R code

```
knn.pred <- knn(tdm.stack.nl_train, tdm.stack.nl_Test, tdm.cand_train, prob = TRUE)

>     Error in knn(tdm.stack.nl_train, tdm.stack.nl_Test, tdm.cand_train, prob = TRUE) : 
>       dims of 'test' and 'train' differ.
```

I want to print the error message as given below. However I could not achieve this. I am not good in writing functions yet.. Please help.

```
   out <- tryCatch( when error = {print('New words seen in testing data')})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
tryCatch(knn.pred <- knn(tdm.stack.nl_train, tdm.stack.nl_Test, tdm.cand_train, prob = TRUE),
         error = function(e) {
           stop('New words seen in testing data')
         })
```

This shows up as:

```
 tryCatch(knn.pred <- knn(tdm.stack.nl_train, tdm.stack.nl_Test, tdm.cand_train, prob = TRUE),
          error = function(e) {
            stop('New words seen in testing data')
            })

 Error in value[[3L]](cond) : New words seen in testing data
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This has worked. By the way can you just explain me what this function(e) means here? Thanks again.

Comment: @Arun You are welcome, glad I could be of help. The `function(e)` bit is called an [anonymous function](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html). The argument error needs a function that will call if an error occurs in `tryCatch`. Since we want it to stop and print a specific error, we do it by using an anonymous function which does exactly that. An anonymous function is literally a normal function with the only exception that it doesn't have a name (and thus anonymous).

Comment: And the `e` in `function(e)` is arbitrary. Essentially it can be anything you like. You could use `function(whatever)` if you liked. People usually use `e` because it is the first letter of `error`.

Comment: awesome explanation. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

It's better and easier to use try:

```
knn.pred <- try(knn(tdm.stack.nl_train, tdm.stack.nl_Test, tdm.cand_train, prob = TRUE))

if (inherits(knn.pred, "try-error") { # error management
  print('New words seen in testing data')
}
```